# inserting sweeping into android tab page

Tags: android

good morning guys, this question might be simple for many of you , but im not adept at UI yet :)  could you guys help me how can i implement sweeping in into this tab page?

```
 public class AndroidTabAndListView extends TabActivity {
// TabSpec Names
private static final String INBOX_SPEC = "Inbox";
private static final String OUTBOX_SPEC = "Outbox";
private static final String PROFILE_SPEC = "Profile";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    // Inbox Tab
    TabSpec inboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(INBOX_SPEC);
    // Tab Icon
    inboxSpec.setIndicator(INBOX_SPEC, 
getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_inbox));
    Intent inboxIntent = new Intent(this, InboxActivity.class);
    // Tab Content
    inboxSpec.setContent(inboxIntent);

    // Outbox Tab
    TabSpec outboxSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(OUTBOX_SPEC);
    outboxSpec.setIndicator(OUTBOX_SPEC, 
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_outbox));
    Intent outboxIntent = new Intent(this, OutboxActivity.class);
    outboxSpec.setContent(outboxIntent);

    // Profile Tab
    TabSpec profileSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec(PROFILE_SPEC);
    profileSpec.setIndicator(PROFILE_SPEC, 
 getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_profile));
    Intent profileIntent = new Intent(this, ProfileActivity.class);
    profileSpec.setContent(profileIntent);

    // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
    tabHost.addTab(inboxSpec); // Adding Inbox tab
    tabHost.addTab(outboxSpec); // Adding Outbox tab
    tabHost.addTab(profileSpec); // Adding Profile tab
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have to recommend you to abandon deprecated TabHost and implement what you need using [ActionBarSherlock](http://vinaygopinath.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/navigation-tabs-with-fragments-using-actionbarsherlock/)[1](http://vinaygopinath.wordpress.com/2012/05/24/navigation-tabs-with-fragments-using-actionbarsherlock/).

It has multiple pros:

1) You won't load an activity for every tab, instead you'll inflate the activity content into a view, this would enhance the performance of your app.

2) Good documentary about the library and lots of examples.

3) Contains embedded ViewPager for the swiping

Comment: but last time a took a look at it , sherlock didnt have swiping tabs ability did it?